# How to track the window size in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to track the window size and create some changes based on the window width.

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;

window.addEventListener('resize',change);
function change(){
    if (w<1000){
        console.log('yes')
    }
    else{
        console.log('no');
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However the output is always stuck on either 'yes' or 'no' based on the initial window size, when the window width is first changed.
What changes should I make to ensure that appropriate response is shown when the window width is greater than or lesser 1000px?

Comment: You need to move the line `var w = window.innerWidth;` inside your `change` function otherwise the value never updates.

Comment: Don't even store it in a variable - you are just adding a variable where you don't need it. Just point to `window.innerWidth` directly.

Comment: yeah, this answers my question

Comment: *create some changes based on the window width* - use CSS media queries.  Depends on what the "changes" will be ofc, but you shouldn't be doing too much on a resize.  Consider *debouncing* resize event if you are doing anything complicated otherwise UX will be terrible.